# Snowflake VARCHAR to VARIANT Inserting "\" characters

Tags: json, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I have some raw data in a varchar column but when I run the to_variant() function on it the data changes drastically. For example.

This json data stored in varchar

```
{
  "event_detail": {
    "event_name": "quote_created",
    "id": "679cc110-1c06-4f7d-aeed-1f637c0eff2d",
    "source": "Quote service",
    "timestamp": {
      "nanos": 730693300,
      "seconds": 1603366821
    }
  }
```

Turns into this

```
"{
   \"event_detail\": {
     \"event_name\": \"quote_created\",
     \"id\": \"679cc110-1c06-4f7d-aeed-1f637c0eff2d\",
     \"source\": \"Quote service\",
     \"timestamp\": {
       \"nanos\": 730693300,
       \"seconds\": 1603366821
    }
  }"
```

Has anyone seen this before? It makes parsing the variant extremely difficult? I've also seen the first json payload stored without "\" characters in variant data types before.

Comment: Is it not escaping the quotes?

Comment: if you do select to_variant(<json here>) it will output the above. It doesn't seem to be escaping the quotes!

Answer (score 4):

As I know, it's expected behaviour. Instead of converting varchar to variant using to_variant function, you may use parse_json function. In this case, it would be easy to parse:

```
select parse_json('{  "event_detail": {
    "event_name": "quote_created",
    "id": "679cc110-1c06-4f7d-aeed-1f637c0eff2d",
    "source": "Quote service",
    "timestamp": {
      "nanos": 730693300,
      "seconds": 1603366821 }}}'):event_detail.event_name::String;
```

This will return: *quote_created*

Comment: I see the same behavior when I use `write_pandas` from `snowflake.connector` Was wondering is there any way to prevent this, but I think it's expected behavior.

Comment: Parsing varchar over variant is much slower that is why we’re trying to store as variant.

Answer (score 0):

Since @demircioglu mentioned **write_pandas()**:

I too once had this "behavior" when uploading json with python to a snowflake table with VARIANT column.

To eradicate the backslashes, when I load the table into snowflake I additionally run the following update-statement:

```
conn.cursor().execute("update YOUR_db.YOUR_schema.YOUR_table set some_column =parse_json(replace(some_column, '\', ''))")
```

Should be fine then ;)